# Laravel 4.2 installed in a subdirectory, but not included in URLs

Tags: url, laravel, subdirectory

I'm just after installing Laravel into a subdirectory `http://domain.com/~username/` but my URLs are all being output from the root `http://domain.com/` instead of the installed subdirectory.

I'm using `URL::to('example/page');` to generate URLs but this outputs incorrectly

Outputs: `http://domain.com/example/page`

Should output: `http://domain.com/~username/example/page`.

I have `'url' => 'http://domain.com/~username'` set in my `app.php` file. *(have tried with/without trailing slash)*

I did find a workaround by using `Config::get('app.url')`, this outputs the URL correctly, but I'd rather not because I'd have to go through my code to change everything over to that.

Has anyone else had this issue? It seems to me like a pretty big bug to me in Laravel or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong URL helper for this.

Wherever you need to generate a URL: ([URL Helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls))

```
$url = route('routeName', $params);
```

And in your routes.php: ([Named Routes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes))

```
Route::get('user/profile', array('as' => 'routeName', function()
{
    //
}));
```

You could also make your routes all point to Controller Methods and use:

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

And wherever you need a URL:

```
$url = action('UserController@showProfile');
```

These methods can mixed and matched like this:

In routes.php

```
Route::get('user/profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));
```

Wherever you need the URL

```
$url = action('UserController@showProfile');
$url = route('profile', $params);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it looks a lot cleaner anyway but I tried `{{ link_to('example/page') }}` and it's still being output as `http://domain.com/example/page` instead of `http://domain.com/~username/example/page`

Comment: What I do in my applications is this: My routes ALL point to controller actions and I use action('SomeAction@SomeController'); to create my links. Try that one.

Comment: Corrected my answer for you.